# fetch json data based on data-identity

Tags: jquery-mobile

Again m posting on SO since m getting answers on all questions i have during the building of my first jquerymobile project. the issue now is that i need to retrieve specific data from a json already loaded. my json gets 2 rows from news table and display the news title in a list view. what i need is that when i click on a list to display the description of the news i clicked on. So far i am able to get the news_id of the list i click on but now i need to access json and get the needed data based on that id. the code i did to get the id is:

a href='#NewsDetails' data-identity='"+v.news_id+"'

and on click of the list i have the below to get the id:
$("a[href=#NewsDetails]").live(
                  "click",
                  function(e) {
                     navIdentity = $(this).data("identity");
             alert(navIdentity);
                  }
            );
All is fine till now but the only thing i need is to access json using navIdentity and get the needed row to display it.
Counting on ur professional replies as usual...

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

So you have your json data available and you have the "id" of the element that you want... so just loop through the json until you find what you're looking for. If you have some sample json data I could give you a better example, but it would look something like this:

```
$.each(data.newsDetails, function(index, newsDetail) {
    if(newsDetail.id === navIdentity) {
        // do something with newsDetail
        return false; // break out of loop
    }
})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i didn't find what exactly m searching for. Can you help by giving me an example if possible? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks man, i tried it and it worked perfect for me. Thank you very much.